# Usage of "conjuncture "

Tags: word-usage

The Merriam-Webster dictionary gives the meaning of "conjuncture" as:

> Definition of conjuncture
>
> 1 : CONJUNCTION, UNION
>
> 2 : a combination of circumstances or events usually producing a crisis : JUNCTURE

Can the phrase "conjuncture of events " can be replaced with "series of events "? According to definition 2, is the word "events" is extra in the above phrase? Is the word only can be used for events? As according to definition 1,it is not limited to events only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've occasionally seen "conjunction", or "juncture", but never "conjuncture".  It would probably confuse me since it's very similar to "conjecture", which has a different meaning.  Since I have never seen it used in context, I would assume it has the same meaning as "conjunction", which is simply a meeting of two things -- people, events, things, ideas, etc.

I advise not using "conjuncture", if for no other reason than the "con" seems redundant. "Juncture" seems to mean the same thing, and is a relatively common term.   For example:

> At this particular **juncture**, the Federal Reserve has decided not to raise interest rates, as it could depress spending and deepen the economic slowdown.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the OP means that. In Spanish and French, etc. it means: a series of event that occur at the same time.

Comment: @Lambie  if that's the case, it's probably a leftover from old French.  Do you think the appropriate English equivalent is "conjunction"?

Comment: No, in fact things like (Spanish) coyuntura actual (French: conjoncture actuelle) mean the present state of the economy, believe it or not. Conjunction is what translators who are not very good come up with. :) It's a red-flag term. That's why it jumped out at me. for events, it can be: the coming together of a series of events at a particular moment in time...but the OP seems disinterested. Too bad...:)

Comment: @Lambie So,this means that "conjuncture of events means "series of events"?

Comment: @lyk  I think that only makes it more redundant.